# VS Code Task that opens a corresponding spec file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, editor

I would like to create a keybind that opens the corresponding unit test file for the currently open file. There is a directory structure in my project that enables this mapping. The path for a file that can be unit tested in the project root has the first directory replaced with `spec/`, and suffixed with `_spec.rb` in place of the original extension.

So if I have a class defined in `app/controller/something.rb`, and a corresponding unit test for the class exists at `spec/controller/something_spec.rb`.

I have this:

```json
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Open RSpec",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "/usr/local/bin/code ${workspaceFolder}/spec/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}_spec.rb"
    }
  ]
}
```

But the problem is that `relativeFileDirname` has `app` in the path. Is there a way to trim or regex variables in the task? Or another strategy altogether?

Comment: I think there is a extension for that: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Thadeu.vscode-run-rspec-file.  Feature: Search and Run Spec based current file with cmd+alt+l (RSpec: Run File on RSpec)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file) and the command `htmlRelatedLinks.openFile`

Define the following key binding (change the key combo if needed):

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+i r",
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": {
      "file": "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFile:find=^.*?/(.*?)(\\.rb)$:replace=$1_spec.rb}",
      "method": "vscode.open",
      "viewColumn": "split"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == ruby"
  }
```

It removes the first directory of the `${relativeFile}` and replaces the text `.rb` with `_spec.rb`

Doing the reverse is a bit difficult because the initial folder is not constant.

If you are on Windows you have to change the separator to double backslash.

Comment: Hmm for some reason the `"file"` value isn't undergoing transformation. In my key bindings:

`"file": "${file}"`

The keybinding attempts to open the file at path literal `$file`

Comment: @Jeesubmunu because `${file}` is not a variable implemented in the extension. use `${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFile}`

Comment: @Jeesubmunu why do you use `${file}`? How will you be able to split of the first part of the relative path for any workspace

Comment: I used `${file}` as a simpler case because I also couldn't get `${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFile}` to transform.

Comment: @Jeesubmunu Do you have it working without transforms, do you have the extension installed, does it need a Reload